# Is it possible to have the Kontact suite on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, kubuntu, kontact

I'd like to have the whole `Kontact` suite all together instead of i.e.  Kmail and Korganizer split up. As those two programs are downloadable from Ubuntu Software, but not the suite.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and would like to avoid having to install Kubuntu or switching from GNOME to KDE.

Regards.

Comment: Can you put a link of Kalendar app from official source. It seems there is no KDE packages with name `kalendar`. Where did you get the name from?

Comment: Sorry I meant `Korganizer`

Comment: You want to install both with a single command instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just install `kontact`. This will bring both of those packages. Because `kontact` recommends those and default `apt` settings for Ubuntu is treating recommended applications as dependency

Here is the output of `apt-cache depends kontact`

```
→ apt-cache depends kontact
kontact
  Depends: kdepim-runtime
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libkf5completion5
  Depends: libkf5configcore5
  Depends: libkf5configgui5
  Depends: libkf5configwidgets5
  Depends: libkf5coreaddons5
  Depends: libkf5i18n5
  Depends: libkf5iconthemes5
  Depends: libkf5identitymanagement5
  Depends: libkf5kcmutils5
  Depends: libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5
  Depends: libkf5kiowidgets5
  Depends: libkf5kontactinterface5
  Depends: libkf5libkdepim5
  Depends: libkf5parts5
  Depends: libkf5service-bin
  Depends: libkf5service5
  Depends: libkf5webkit5
  Depends: libkf5widgetsaddons5
  Depends: libkf5windowsystem5
  Depends: libkf5xmlgui5
  Depends: libqt5core5a
  Depends: libqt5dbus5
 |Depends: libqt5gui5
  Depends: libqt5gui5-gles
  Depends: libqt5webkit5
  Depends: libqt5widgets5
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Recommends: accountwizard
  Recommends: akregator
  Recommends: kaddressbook
  Recommends: kmail
  Recommends: knotes
  Recommends: korganizer
  Suggests: gnokii
```

So, install it with the command

```
sudo apt-get install kontact
```

Hope that helps.